# Woocommerce Change product price by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an array with product id (`post_id`). My goal is to loop thru this array and change all the product prices in WooCommerce products.

Here is my attempt:

```
foreach ($array as $product) {
    update_post_meta($product['post_id'], '_regular_price', $array['price']);
}
```

**Array**

```
[
  {
    "post_id": 18,
    "sku": "SNTP-UVS8P",
    "price": "59.00"
  },
  {
    "post_id": 17,
    "sku": "TD-SKU30548",
    "price": "10.00"
  },
  {
    "post_id": 16,
    "sku": "USBCV",
    "price": "29.00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array['price']` will return undefined change it to `$product['price']`

```
foreach ($array as $product) {
  update_post_meta($product['post_id'], '_regular_price', $product['price']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go about this is that you can use `wc_get_product(ID)` and then use `set_price` on the product object to set your price

sample:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $wc_product = wc_get_product( $product['id'] );
    $product->set_price( $product['price'] );
    $product->save();
}
```